# android Toast: positioning it right on bottom of imageview

Tags: android, android-toast

I am currently developing a game for android and I would like to know how I can change a toast position to be exactly at the bottom of an imageView. I can't "just play with offsets", I need it to be exactly on bottom of an ImageView also shown on the same screen I make the toast.

Comment: I think a `Toast` is not what you need, since they are designed as "on-screen message" rather than "on-view message". You better implement similar behavior yourself - it's not hard.

Comment: can you guide me how?

Comment: The most basic approach: Create TextView with grey (or any) background -> translate it beneath ImageView using `setTranslationX()` and `setTranslationY()`